# Lambda Function Errors When Updating MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to Web Dev and I am a bit in over my head. I am trying to run a task using a Lambda function to grab a random object from an array of objects and uppdate the only document in my MongoDB Collection

currently, it is returning this error

```
{
  "errorType": "object",
  "errorMessage": "[object Promise]",
  "trace": []
}
```

If someone could also help me understand why that would be great!

Here is what I am working with

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

const MONGODB_URI =
  "Removed for Privacy";

let cachedDb = null;

async function connectToDatabase() {
  if (cachedDb) {
    return cachedDb;
  }

  // Connect to our MongoDB database hosted on MongoDB Atlas
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI);

  // Specify which database we want to use
  const db = await client.db("redacted");

  cachedDb = db;
  return db;
}


exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  const db = await connectToDatabase();

    const WORDS = [ { "word": 'exampleWord', "description": 'exampleDescription' }]
    
    let wotd = WORDS[Math.floor(Math.random() * WORDS.length)]
    
    
    let updateWord = db.collection('wordoftheday').updateOne({"_id":"ObjectId('redacted')"},{$set: {
      "word": wotd.word,
      "description": wotd.description}})
  
    callback(updateWord)
    
    };
```

Comment: Traditionally, callbacks in nodejs are of the form `callback(err?)`. Running `callback(updateWord)` is very similar to `throw updateWord`. You should probably just `await` the update and then invoke the callback with no args.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding await statement to wait for database update record and return the updated record

```
let updateWord = await db.collection('wordoftheday').updateOne({"_id": new ObjectId('redacted')},{$set: {
      "word": wotd.word,
      "description": wotd.description}})
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! Your edits helped it run without error. However, it didnt update the document. I got this reponse: {
  "acknowledged": true,
  "modifiedCount": 0,
  "upsertedId": null,
  "upsertedCount": 0,
  "matchedCount": 0
} any ideas?

Comment: Because you _id you provide is not correct, please check your 'new ObjectId('redacted')', I don't know what 'redacted' is but you must provide the _id of record that you want to update

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I put redacted so that you could not see my real object id. I have it set up in this format {"_id":"ObjectId('123456778965443')"} is this correct?

Comment: This is the correct syntax: {"_id": new ObjectId("6384dfb19ac520dce2860ebf")}. In addition, you must import ObjectId from related library which you use to connect to MongoDB

Comment: sorry, maybe I have not set it up properly. I am not trying to create a new ObjectId. I am trying to update the document by querying for its Id. Is there something else I can use to query the document? It is the only doc in the collection

Comment: if you provide "6384dfb19ac520dce2860ebf", Mongo uses this as String type, but your _id is the primary key and always is ObjectId Type, so you must convert String to ObjectId.